Why I can't copy file with Shutil?
When I try to copy file in new path with shutil like this:
shutil.copy("data/Обзор кассационной практики Судебной коллегии по уголовным делам Верховного Суда Российской Федерации за первое полугодие 2010 год.pdf",
"new_files/обзор кассационной практики судебной коллегии по уголовным делам верховного суда российской федерации за первое полугодие 2010 года от от 13 октября 2010 г..pdf")

I get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-a9ee87b5f1e8> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 shutil.copy("data/Обзор кассационной практики Судебной коллегии по уголовным делам Верховного Суда Российской Федерации за первое полугодие 2010 год.pdf",
      2 "new_files/обзор кассационной практики судебной коллегии по уголовным делам верховного суда российской федерации за первое полугодие 2010 года от от 13 октября 2010 г..pdf".strip())

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/shutil.py in copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks)
    254         with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
    255             try:
--> 256                 with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    257                     # macOS
    258                     if _HAS_FCOPYFILE:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'new_files/обзор кассационной практики судебной коллегии по уголовным делам верховного суда российской федерации за первое полугодие 2010 года от от 13 октября 2010 г..pdf'


I really don't understand why it happens. I can do it by hands, so this new name is good enough. But not with Shutil.
I tried to strip my new name, but it didn't help. I don't see any bad symbol there.

Your destination filename is 283 bytes long, in utf-8 format.  The limit is 255...

@jasonharper if destination name too long the error will be OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long .... innit?

shutil defers to the OS, so you're going to have to [edit] your post to include what OS you're running this on, as well as which version of Python you're using.

@DmitriGalkin: Yes, that's the error on Linux (and the limit is 1023). Likely the OP is using a different operating system. For example, on Windows the limit is 255 (16-bit characters). Maybe the OP is using WSL2.

Most likely you are using a filename (or pathname) too long for your system. Try it with a shorter pathname, e.g.
shutil.copy("data/Обзор кассационной практики Судебной коллегии по уголовным делам Верховного Суда Российской Федерации за первое полугодие 2010 год.pdf",
"new_files/test.pdf")

Depending on the operating system and the filesystem, there may be size limits on the base filename (test.pdf), on the specified pathname (new_files/test.pdf), on the filesystem pathname (e.g. buf/new_files/test.pdf) and/or on the full absolute pathname (e.g. /media/user/fs/buf/new_files/test.pdf). Typical size limits: 255, 1023, 4095. Your code may be hitting a limit of 255.

This is really more of a comment than an answer, though.
